# Reading text rendered with direct3d in another program in C#

Tags: c#, c++, hook

I'm not new to programming, but I have a Unix/Linux background and Windows programming is a bit new to me. Given I have another program installed and running that uses Direct3d to render text I'd like to hook into those text rendering routines to read what is being drawn and where it's being drawn on the screen.

I've already written a C# program that finds the handle for the process I'm interested in, and can interact with it by emulating mouse clicks and keyboard strokes. However, it uses checksums of screenshots to determine what's happening on the screen and it's just too clumsy. OCR is also not a good option here. I've programmed C/C++ before, so if I need to use that instead of, or in combination with, C# that's fine.

I've searched extensively on this and I'm pretty sure it's possible, but does anyone know of some tutorials/examples on how to get started with this?

Comment: http://spazzarama.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/screen-capture-with-direct3d-api-hooks/

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the [Detours libs from microsoft research](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/), though they *might* still have an option for free usage.